# What scannable barcode formats supported by zxing are usable open source?

Tags: barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an android application where in I generate data matrices and allow users to input them using zxing  for scanning them.

However, there was a license issue raised asking if all the formats scanned by zxing available open source.

It's not about the application zxing but the formats it scans. Are all those formats usable under some or other open source license. If not, which scannable formats are open source usable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all are open, or else they wouldn't be implemented. For example, MS Tag is not there. Data Matrix was originally patented and proprietary when invented, but at this point is ISO standard 16022 and is public domain. Something similar happened with QR Codes, for example.